# Mongoengine: insert ListField item into a specific embedded Document

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a Document and an embedded document and I want to insert a value to a ListField of my embeddded document. I couldnt find anything about this problem on stackoverflow so maybe anyone can help me out.

This is basically my model class:

```
class Person(EmbeddedDocument):
    oid = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId,
                        unique=True, primary_key=True, sparse=True)
    personName = StringField()
    charakterEntries= ListField()

class schoolClass(Document):
    className= StringField(unique=true)
    persons = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Personn))
```

so I want to go into a specific person of a specific class and insert a new charakter entry to the listField charakterEntries.

Lets say I have a `className "chemistry"` and want to insert the new `charakter entry "polite"` to the `ListField "charakterEntries"` of the Person who has the `oid="abc123"`.

I though I could do something like this:

```
 person= Person.objects(oid=id).get()
    person.charakterEntries.append("polite")
    person.save()
```

But then I get the following error: `AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'objects'`

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I've tried a lot of things here on stackoverflow but couldt make it work. So please don't close this question  right away.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution:

```
 schoolClass.objects.filter(persons__oid="abc123").update_one(
        push__persons__S__charakterEntries="polite")
```

This puts the new charakter entry polite to the end of the ListField.